# DynamoDB Modeling Multiple Query Elements

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

**Background:** I have a relational db background and have never built anything for DynamoDB that wasn't just used for fast writes with very few reads.  I am trying to learn DynamoDB patterns by migrating one of my help desk apps from MySQL to DynamoDB.

The application is a fairly simple one from a data storage perspective.  A user submits a request and that request generates 1 or more tickets.

**Setup:** I have screens where people see initial requests and that request's tickets and search views that allow support to query on a bunch of attributes of a ticket (last name of user, status of ticket, use case of ticket, phone number of user, dept of user).  This design in a SQL db is pretty straightforward but in Dynamo, I'm really being thrown for a loop on how to structure primary/sort keys and secondary indexes (if necessary).

I created one collection for requests and one collection for tickets.  The individual requests have an array of ticket ids that belong to it.  The ticket item has an attribute that stores the request id so that I can search that way.  But what I am hung up on, is how do I incorporate searching on a ticket/request's attributes without having to do a full scan?

I read about composite keys and perhaps creating a composite sort key similar to: ## so that I can search on each of those fields directly without having to know the primary key (ticket id).

**Question:** How do you design dynamo collections/tables that require querying a lot of different attribute values without relying on a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically something that DynamoDB is not good at, not to say it definitely cannot be done. The strength and speed for DynamoDB comes from having well known access patterns and designing your schema for these patterns. In general if you don't know what your users will search for, or there are many different possible queries, it's better to look at something like RDS or a native SQL DB. That being said a possible direction to solve this could be to create multiple lists for each of the fields and duplicate the data. This could all be done in the same table.

Comment: There were just too many fields to query off of that would've required me trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.  I think I have a better idea of what use cases Dynamo would be better for now.